# I need help making an API request to an external API in nodejs express server (Angular Universal)

Tags: node.js, angular, api, express, universal

I have an Angular Universal app. I am trying to access an external API, but doing it directly through the HttpClient generates a Cors error. In development, I successfully used a proxy to make the call. I am trying to implement a proxy in production by creating a route on my express server that will swap in the appropriate external API route. I am having trouble seeing anything online that can help with this particular situation. I seem to have set up the route ok. I'm getting a 200 ok error but no data is being sent. Can anyone help?

server.ts

```
app.route('/api/book').get((req, res) => {

  https.get('https://api2.isbndb.com/book/' + req, (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on('end', () => {
      res.send(res.json(data)
      );
    });

  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  });


});
```

[image: console message]

Comment: Why do you need a proxy for production? The cors error mostly appears only when using localhost or when you are missing these headers. You can also add cors to express with [this](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) package.

Comment: That's a great question. I'm really not sure why I need a proxy. I was working fine not using a proxy up until a couple of days ago. I know I have the correct headers and API keys. but suddenly I get cors errors every time. and I am using that package

Comment: Hard to tell what is going wrong. Did you make changes on the environment? Do you use nginx or apache ?

Comment: I'm using express. No other servers. Not familiar with nginx or apache.

Comment: what error do you get when you dont use the proxy in production? I see you are using aws, maybe [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) helps?

Comment: I get your basic CORS error:  "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api2.isbndb.com/book/0123456789' from origin 'https://or8ui13hvi.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Comment: maybe isbndb is blocking requests from aws domains & localhost.

Comment: it’s possible. the thing is when i used a proxy in developement (ng serve) the api call went through no sweat. but there is no easy option for that in production i’ll look into the cors policy stuff on aws

Comment: You are sending the request from aws to isbndb. **isbndb is blocking your request origin from aws** Any chance to test another origin ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply enable cors from your server side like this.

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

For better understanding or to configure cors() url through.
can see [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

As by default it will call the options method to check the permission for the user to access that end points.

or you can use below example from client side api call,

```
let data = { name: 'Peter Parker', age: 34 };
 const results = await fetch(
  'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/results',
  {
    method: "post", 
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }
)
  .then(res => res.json()) 
  .then(res => {
    return res;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    error.response = {
      status: 0,
      statusText:
        "Cannot connect. Please make sure you are connected to internet."
    };
    throw error;
  });
```